# Extra vs. Excess (specific)

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

I am fairly confident that I have a decent understanding of the differences between 'extra' and 'excess', but there's been one specific context that had me scratching my head as of late. Say I want to express that I brought an ample amount of money (way more that I'd likely need) to spend at a cash-only store, which of the two words would be more appropriate? For example:

> I was just short at the checkout last time, so I brought ***EXTRA*** // ***EXCESS*** money with me today.

To share my own thoughts, I feel that 'excess' has a retrospective vibe to it, as in you'd only know you have more than you need after the event. But 'extra' doesn't seem to be the perfect fit either, as it conveys that you already know exactly how much you will spent/need and just add an additional amount to that. (e.g. I know the stuff I am going to buy cost $200, but I brought an extra $50 just in case I might want to pick up some other stuff along the way.)

Note that the paragraph above is just my personal view. I would like hear a comprehensive answer that would confirm my understanding as well as correct it. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: _Excess_ means 'more than required/allowed', whereas _extra_ simply means 'more', with the context providing the comparison. Here _extra money_ would mean 'more money than I brought before' or 'more money than I thought I'd need', while _excess money_ just means 'too much money'.

Comment: so I brought excess money with me would mean: so I brought too much money with me. Clearly, you can see that is not right, right?

Comment: The two words are closely related, but the difference in meaning should be clear if you look them both up in the dictionary. If you need clarification beyond the dictionary definitions, perhaps you can post again with specifics of what you don't understand in them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your general understanding of

> excess
>   extra

is correct.

If you already have an amount and then *have a bit more*, that is

> **extra cash**

if you know how much you *need* and have some left over, that is

> **excess cash**

Often "**extra**" gets used when "**excess**" should be, but will still be understood

> I brought **extra** cash with me, so I have *(an)* **excess** *(of)* cash in my pocket, and **extra** cash to spend.
>   I brought **extra** cash with me, so I have **extra** cash in my pocket, and **extra** cash to spend.

in the second sentence, "**extra**" is used to mean "*more than enough*", but

> I brought **excess** cash with me, so I have **excess** cash in my pocket, and **excess** cash to spend.

does not work.

When checking in at UK airports, if you bring

> extra bags

you will need to check them in as

> excess baggage